# Set custom id in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am using Angular to build a SELECT using ng-options, and all is working minus the fact I would like to set the value rather than having Angular auto-populate that.

```
$scope.form.stage = [{ 
       optional: 1
       id: 23
       description: UD Visual Inspection - optional
     },{ 
       optional: 0
       id: 12
       description: Flash
     }]
```

**My directive:**

```
<select name='test_stage' ng-model='form.selectedStage' ng-change='abc(form)' ng-options='item.description for item in form.stage'>
```

**Rendered HTML**:

```
<select name="test_stage" id="test_form_stage" tabindex="2" ng-model="form.selectedStage" ng-change="abc(form)" ng-options="item.description for item in form.stage" ng-blur="fetchTestStation(form)" class="ng-valid ng-dirty"><option value="0">UD Visual Inspection - optional</option><option value="1">Flash</option></select>
```

Instead of having the values be set to 0 and 1 I want 23 and 12...

**Update Rendered HTML:**

```
<select name="test_stage" id="test_form_stage" tabindex="2" ng-model="form.selectedStage" ng-change="abc(form)" ng-options="item.id as item.description for item in form.stage" ng-blur="fetchTestStation(form)" class="ng-valid ng-dirty"><option value="0">UD Visual Inspection - optional</option><option value="1">Flash</option></select>
```

**Updated: 7-25-15**

```
form:  { 
    selectedStage: null
    stage: 
 [{ 
    optional: 1
    id: 23
    description: UD Visual Inspection - optional
 },{ 
    optional: 0
    id: 13
    description: Engraving
 }]
} 
    selectedStage:  { 
        $ref: $["form"]["stage"][1]
}
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<select name="test_stage" id="test_form_stage" tabindex="2" ng-model="form.selectedStage" ng-options="item as item.description for item in form.form.stage" ng-blur="fetchTestStation(form)" class="ng-valid ng-dirty"><option value="?"></option><option value="0">UD Visual Inspection - optional</option><option value="1">Engraving</option></select>
```

**My Controller**
        $scope.fetchTestRecord = function($scope){

```
    // Set vars
    $scope.workorder = {};
    $scope.product = {};

    // Set params to send in request
    var params = $.param({
        serial: $scope.serial
    });

    /**
     * Get stage data for serial from API [Factory]
     */
    tstFrmServices.locateRecord(params).success(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;

        // Handle successfull response
        if ($scope.data['success'][0].code == 200){

             $scope.form = {
                selectedStage: null,
                stage: $scope.data['success'][0].data
              };

            $scope.workorder = $scope.data['success'][0].wo;
            $scope.product = $scope.data['success'][0].product;
        }


    }).error(function (result) {

    });
};
```

});

**Data returned from Factory**

```
"data": [{"optional": 1, "id": 23, "description": "UD Visual Inspection - optional"}, {"optional": 0, "id": 13, "description": "Engraving"}], "product": "10P91685-010"}]}
```

Comment: I think you need to use the track by syntax: ng-options='item.description for item in form.stage track by id'

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select) explains how to do that quite clearly (`select as …`).

Comment: 'track by id' is only rendering a single option box (the first one) with a value of '?'

Comment: Have also tried this with no luck ----  ng-options='select as description for (id, description) in form.stage'

Comment: `item.id as item.description for item in form.stage`

Comment: @blackhole - I tried that a while ago with no luck as well, see updated HTML output

Comment: Whats with the downvote, clearly this isnt a clear cut as it may seem and the documentation on the site doesn't clearly cover this scenario...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let `selectedStage` be the entire selected object, you can get the value you want from `form.selectedStage.id`

```
<select name='test_stage' 
  ng-model='form.selectedStage' 
  ng-change='abc(form)' 
  ng-options='item as item.description for item in form.stage'>
</select>
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/fsn5qakC6nKUOdQKhYjR/preview

Comment: Thats for the help so far the plunker was definitely useful. I went down this path originally but seemed to be having issues with the selectedStage getting malformed JSON possibly, (see update above).

When I select a stage the selectedStage model gets that $ref in it rather than the values, also when I inspect the element I am not seeing my ID's for the value. Not sure where I am going wrong with this task.

Comment: Nevermind, made this tweak and it seems to be working: ng-options='item.id as item.description for item in form.form.stage'